# How to draw a canvas on a specific area of the screen? Also rotating that canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

The problem I encounter is that I am trying to draw a canvas inside a phone which has a transparent screen which I photoshopped. The is tilted a little bit and I want to create a game in the phone screen. The problem is that I need probably to have the X and Y coordinates to point out which area the canvas must be drawn.

Best regards, Tar2ed

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYLlL.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWlGy.jpg)

Comment: Determine the appropriate position, rotation and clip. Apply those with the transformation functions, then `ctx.save()` - now you can just draw to the canvas normally and it'll work. You'll have to figure out the values based on your source image, but it should be relatively easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using 2 canvas objects (or a regular image for the background), to deal more easily with the two distinct 2D transforms for the 2 spaces (the background is a null-transform, while for the game canvas you will need a 2D transform that accounts for rotation and maybe perspective). So the easiest would be to use two html objects, absolutely positioned one above the other. Then you set the game canvas 2D transform matrix (you need to build or compute that starting from the screen corner points on your background image) and you are good to go.